# CS0123 C# No overload for 'Polar_Checked' matches delegate 'RoutedEventHandler'

Tags: c#

My professor assigned a C# sharp project where we have to convert coordinates from polar to rectangular form and vice versa. I have very little knowledge of C# (my professor literally taught us nothing about it besides how to install it) and I keep having this error on multiple lines of code.

"No overload for 'Polar_Checked' matches delegate 'RoutedEventHandler' (Line 20)

"No overload for 'Converter_Click' matches delegate 'RoutedEventHandler' (Line 22)

"No overload for 'TextBox_TextChanged' matches delegate 'TextChangedEventHandler' (Line 23)

"No overload for 'Angle_TextChanged' matches delegate 'TextChangedEventHandler' (Line 24)

```
    public delegate int TextChangedEventHandler();
    public MainWindow(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Polar_Checked(object sender, TextChangedEventHandler e)
    {

    }

    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventHandler e)
    {

    }

    public void TextBox_TextChanged_1(object sender, TextChangedEventHandler e)
    {
        double mag;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
        mag = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    public void Angle_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventHandler e)
    {
        double ang;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
        ang = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    }
    private void Converter_Click(object sender, TextChangedEventHandler e, double ang, double mag)
    {
        if (Polar.IsChecked == true)
        {
            double x;
            double y;
            x = (Math.Cos(ang) * mag);
            y = Math.Sin(ang) * mag;
            Console.Write(x);
            Console.Write(y);
        }
        else if (Rectangular.IsChecked == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Goodbye.");
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Not to answer your question, but judging by the names of `TextBox_TextChanged` and `TextBox_TextChanged_1`, I would assume you auto-generated the first one, removed the reference to that event from the `TextBox`, and then regenerated it to get the 2nd one. Not saying that's 100% the case, but it might be a possible cleanup opportunity. If you do need both of them, you might consider giving them better names.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your WPF form expects [RoutedEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.routedeventhandler?view=netframework-4.8) for some of the events which takes `RoutedEventArgs` as second parameter. This clearly don't match `(object sender, TextChangedEventHandler e)` you have in your code.

To get delegate to match to following:

```
public delegate void RoutedEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);
```

You should use

```
private void Polar_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Same should apply to other events - search MSDN for types and error codes...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Your suggestion worked for all the events except Converter Click